# How to separate authorization server spring security in java

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have started to learn spring security (Oauth2). I am having a REST API service which is protected by Spring Oauth2. What i want to do is, I want to separate authorization server and resource server,  For example,

I am having
Authorization:   http://server1:8080/RESTTest/oauth/token/grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=clientt&client_secret=secret

And 
Resource 
http://server1:8080/RESTTest/api/users/?access_token=2cf682c6-2900-47dc-a468-441fcee0dc18

What i want is,

Authorization : http://Server1:8080/**authorizationserver** /oauth/token/grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=clientt&client_secret=secret

Resource:
http://server2:8080/**RESTTest**/api/users/?access_token=2cf682c6-2900-47dc-a468-441fcee0dc18

I am using **JDBCTokenstore**. I am not sure how to separate it. Can someone help me.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you find a way? I need to do exactly the same thing, for now I have found this http://www.hascode.com/2016/03/setting-up-an-oauth2-authorization-server-and-resource-provider-with-spring-boot/#Tutorial_Sources

Answer (score 1):

You can map your custom endpoint to defaults provided, fyi http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html

```
@Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

            endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
            endpoints.pathMapping("/oauth/token", "/authorizationserver/oauth/token")
        }

}
```

Comment: Hi, The problem is i will deploy Authorization ser ver and resource server as a separate instance. Meaning  server1 will have authorization server , Server2 will have resource server

Comment: @Backtrack , you should be able extend AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter  in same way and then map the path accordingly and in your client you have to provide your new authorization server urls. there are plenty examples available here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth